# How do I calculate received intergeres from the server, and send back the appropriate answer?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I have created a client in python3 where I can receive data from the server, and the output is shown as a column of numbers but the type of data  is a string. So while I am doing this, I will need to convert the column of numbers that is a string to integer to do any calculations. However, here is the latest code I've done, and the errors that I've received showed that the index is out of range.

```py
import socket
import re

SERVER_HOST = "<name of server>"
SERVER_PORT = <port number>
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

host = socket.gethostbyname(SERVER_HOST)
port = SERVER_PORT

server = socket.socket()
server.connect((host, port))

while True:
    data = server.recv(1024)
    print(data)
    res = [int(i) for i in data.split() if i.isdigit()]
    print(str(res))

    multiply_data = int(res[0]) * int(res[1])
    print(multiply_data)

    divide_data = multiply_data / int(res[2])
    print(divide_data)

    server.sendall(str(divide_data))
server.close()
```

I can see the output of numbers, and the strings turned into a array of numbers, and the calculation is being done, but it returned an error on the line where I am multiplying the first two indexes, and the error says "list index out of range".

Comment: Can you post the output and traceback of error as well ?

Comment: It just says: Traceback (most recent call last): File "server.py", line 20, in <module> multiply_data = int(res[0]) * int(res[1]) IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Please update the output (including all prints), string received in "data" and traceback in question. so that it will be useful to others as well to help you.